# Regular expression numerical ranges, e.g 1000 - 2000?

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if a string is in the format: xxx[y-z]

Where y and z are two numbers. E.g y can be 1000 and z can be 2000, in which case these will be valid:

xxx1000
xxx1500
xxx1900
xxx2000

Is there a way to accomplish this in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of evalution should not really be in a regex if you can help it. You can use a regex to run a test on the format, but use other functions to test the content:

```
$in = "xxx1234";
if( preg_match("/^xxx(\d{4})$/",$in,$m) && $m[1] >= 1000 && $m[1] <= 2000) {
    // ok!
}
```

Comment: It would be `$m[0]` for the match though rather than `$m[1]` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: `$m[0]` will give you the entire matched string, whereas you want the subpattern (the digits) to test the numeric value.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point in using a regex here, especially if `y` and `z` are variables. Use the regex to test the format, but then take the right-most n characters (capturing it in a group is the easiest), try to parse it into an integer and test if it's in the range.

If `y` and `z` are constant though, sure go ahead:

```
xxx(2000|1[0-9]{3})$
```

Comment: they are variables, how do you mean taking the rightmost and testing if its in the range? can you show me? they won't always be x000, they can be x283 or x876 or any other combination

Comment: Yeah, sorry I stole the spotlight there, @lc. Have +1 for showing the breaking down of numbers, though. Reminds me of when I had to write a regex to match "a number, enclosed in braces, which can range from 1 to 512 and may be zero-padded to three digits"... fun!

Comment: @Kolink No problem at all and thanks. And yeah, that sounds like a whole lot of fun! Haha

Comment: Even worse, I had to do something similar for a game I'm working on, matching `{XY-Z-N}` with `X` a digit, `Y` an uppercase letter, `Z` a number from 1o 512 with optional zero-padding, and `-N` optional with `N` an optionally zero-padded number from 1 to 16... Whee!